# Cannot install printer driver Canon ir2520 on Ubuntu 18.04 using ./install.sh

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, canon

I tried to install the printer driver for Canon ir2520 using the command `./install.sh` and the terminal said that it could not install. I have already tried to install the `libglade2-0` library using

```
sudo apt-get install libglade2-0
```

and it is still not working.

See the following text message with the terminal output:

```
okky@okky:~/Downloads/Compressed/linux-UFRII-drv-v500-uken-04/linux-UFRII-drv-v500-uken$ sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for okky: 
This installer is recommended for the following distributions that are currently supported as of the release of this installer:
- Fedora/Ubuntu/CentOS 7.6/Debian 8.11/Debian 9.8 or later

If this installer is run under distributions for which the support period has ended, the installation of additional system libraries may be necessary after driver installation is complete.

Note that an internet connection is required for installation.

Do you want to continue with installation? (y/n)y

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Start
#----------------------------------------------------#
Machine Type = x86_64
Package Type = rpm
Package list = 
    ./64-bit_Driver/RPM/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64.rpm

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf upgrade
#----------------------------------------------------#
libjpeg-turbo
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found

beecrypt
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found

beecrypt-devel
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found

libglade2
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found

jbigkit-libs
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found


#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 NG: libjpeg-turbo

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 Replace: beecrypt -> libgcrypt

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf upgrade
#----------------------------------------------------#
libgcrypt
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found


#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 NG: libgcrypt

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 Replace: beecrypt-devel -> libgcrypt-devel

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf upgrade
#----------------------------------------------------#
libgcrypt-devel
./install.sh: line 300: dnf: command not found


#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 NG: libgcrypt-devel

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 NG: libglade2

#----------------------------------------------------#
# dnf install
#----------------------------------------------------#
./install.sh: line 313: dnf: command not found

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Package Check
#----------------------------------------------------#
 NG: jbigkit-libs

Some system libraries could not be installed.
Refer to the Readme file for more information.
Do you want to continue with installation? (y/n)y

#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Printer Driver (rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs)
#----------------------------------------------------#
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libcups.so.2()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libcupsimage.so.2()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libglade-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libglib-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libgobject-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    libxml2.so.2()(64bit) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
    rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk-5.00-1.x86_64
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc35203zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv65553zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc55353zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiprc165zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp323zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf440zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp228zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv45453zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv45253zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp622czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsir1643pzk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp227zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf641czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp621czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv85853zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf645czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp225zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp223zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf741czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiprc710zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsir2635zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf540zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp226zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc2563zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc75803zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupswg7000zzk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv615zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv715zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupswg7000zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsd1600zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv65753zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsir1643izk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc75653zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsir2625zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf745czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv5253zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp852czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc35253zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv7153zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp664czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp663czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc55503zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf642czk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv85053zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradvc4753zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv525zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupslbp222zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsiradv6153zk-5.00-1.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by cnrcupsmf742czk-5.00-1.noarch

#----------------------------------------------------#
# cups restart
#----------------------------------------------------#
/etc/init.d/cups restart
[ ok ] Restarting cups (via systemctl): cups.service.

Could not install.
```

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots of text messages, copy the messages themselves.